# Can't deploy two-service docker image to google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, supervisord, haskell-snap-framework

I've built a docker image which consists of two parts:

- simple nodejs app which is listening to port 8080
- haskell service which is using snap framework (port 8000)

I know that it's better to run those two parts in different containers, but there is a reason to keep them in one. So I found a way how to run two services in one container with the use of supervisord.

In the dockerfile I expose 8080, and when I run the docker image locally it works just fine. I can make POST requests to nodejs app, which in its turn is making POST request to the haskellmodule using port 8000. I run it with the following command:

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 image_name
```

So I pushed the image to google container registry and deployed it with the use of --image-url flag. The deployment process goes without any error, though after that I cannot reach my app. If I look to the running version's logs, I see the following:

```
A  /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/supervisor/options.py:296: UserWarning: Supervisord is running as root and it is searching for its configuration file in default locations (including its current working directory); you probably want to specify a "-c" argument specifying an absolute path to a configuration file for improved security.
A    'Supervisord is running as root and it is searching '
A  2017-10-08 14:08:45,368 CRIT Supervisor running as root (no user in config file)
A  2017-10-08 14:08:45,368 WARN Included extra file "/etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf" during parsing
A  2017-10-08 14:08:45,423 INFO RPC interface 'supervisor' initialized
A  2017-10-08 14:08:45,423 CRIT Server 'unix_http_server' running without any HTTP authentication checking

A  2017-10-08 14:08:45,424 INFO supervisord started with pid 1
A  2017-10-08 14:08:46,425 INFO spawned: 'haskellmodule' with pid 7
A  2017-10-08 14:08:46,427 INFO spawned: 'nodesrv' with pid 8
A  2017-10-08 14:08:47,429 INFO success: haskellmodule entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 0 seconds (startsecs)
A  2017-10-08 14:08:47,429 INFO success: nodesrv entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)

A  2017-10-08 14:13:49,124 WARN received SIGTERM indicating exit request
A  2017-10-08 14:13:49,127 INFO waiting for haskellmodule, nodesrv to die
A  2017-10-08 14:13:49,128 INFO stopped: nodesrv (terminated by SIGTERM)
A  2017-10-08 14:13:49,138 INFO stopped: haskellmodule (terminated by SIGTERM)
```

Then it starts over and everything is repeated over and over again.

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:latest
RUN apt-get update
RUN curl -sSL https://get.haskellstack.org/ | sh
COPY ./nodesrv /nodesrv
COPY ./haskellmodule /haskellmodule 
RUN mkdir /log
WORKDIR /haskellmodule
RUN stack build
WORKDIR /
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y supervisor
ADD ./configs/supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/supervisord"]
```

My supervisord config:

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon=true

[program:nodesrv]
command=node index.js
directory=/nodesrv/
user=root

[program:haskellmodule]
command=stack exec haskellmodule-exe
directory=/haskellmodule/
user=root
```

My app.yaml file I use for deployment:

```
runtime: custom
env: flex
```

So seems like google app engine is shutting supervisor down (taking into account that everything is working on localhost). What could be a reason of that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure your `app.yaml` file to open ports 8080 and 8000. You need to do this **in addition** to opening the port in your Dockerfile with `EXPOSE`. The documentation for how to setup your `app.yaml` file [is located here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml#network_settings), and the example from the docs is copied below:

Add the following to your `app.yaml`:

```
network:
  instance_tag: TAG_NAME
  name: NETWORK_NAME
  subnetwork_name: SUBNETWORK_NAME
  forwarded_ports:
    - PORT
    - HOST_PORT:CONTAINER_PORT
    - PORT/tcp
    - HOST_PORT:CONTAINER_PORT/udp
```

Answer (score 0):

Run supervisord with -n argument.

This will run supervisor in foreground.

Works fine for me in app engine flexible environment.

Thanks